# Remove items from parameters before Mass Assignment error fires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a form where I need to remove some fields from the params in the controller before it is saved (there are no columns for the fields, they are used only to populate linked selects).

The problem is this: I get a mass assignment error for the fields that should not be sent before I have a chance to remove them. I was of the understanding that the error would only fire when the controller gets to `@sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])` but it seems to be occurring before that (I put line at the very start of the controller below, `puts "sale params: " + params[:sale].to_s` but it does not fire, only the mass assignment error occurs.

My controller create action code looks like:

```
def create
  puts "sale params: " + params[:sale].to_s
  params[:sale] = params[:sale].except([:vehicles_attributes])
  @sale = Sale.new(params[:sale])
  if @sale.save
    redirect_to @sale, :notice => "Successfully created address."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

How can I ensure that the :vehicles_attributes hash is removed from params before I get the mass assignment error?

EDIT: Full error, as requested:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SalesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: make, model

Request
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"LX/uEp5o9smc3sCcjQbOXQQgaK2wihvS0OPZTdNOj6w=",
"sale"=>{
  "sale_type_id"=>"1",
  "date"=>"",
    "customer_attributes"=>{
      "customer_type_id"=>"1",
      "emails_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{
          "value"=>""}}},
    "vehicles_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{
         "make"=>"4",
         "model"=>"38",
         "trim_id"=>"658",
         "model_year_id"=>"12"
}}}}
```

Make and Model are the attributes I am trying to remove when I am doing `params[:sale] = params[:sale].except([:vehicles_attributes])` (they are in the :vehicles_attributes hash, as you can see from the error).

Comment: Could you provide the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a LOT of investigating, it turned out that I was unable to remove the parameters from the hash before the error because the `create` method was being overridden by the Cancan gem (when I did `load_and_authorize_resources`.

Removing this solved the problem, when using the code from Frederick Cheung.

Answer (score 1):

Mass assignment occurs inside the call to save. The problem here is that you're not using `except` properly.You're passing an array of keys

```
{:a => :b}.except([:a])
#=> {:a => :b}
```

but it is expecting keys as individual parameters

```
{:a => :b}.except(:a)
#=> {}
```

Comment: Note that you can pass an array as individual parameters with the Ruby splat operator (*): `{:a => :b}.except(*[:a])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to do what you're asking, try:

```
make = params[:sale].delete :make
model = params[:sale].delete :model
```